# Regarding some questions on date of composition of Puranas

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, skanda-purana

It is said that Bhagavata Purana was composed by Vyasa at the end of Dwapara Yuga. In that Purana, all the other major Puranas are mentioned. However, a [chapter](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-ix/chapter-36) in Skanda Purana seems to have mentioned 12th century Jain king. If a 12th century Jain king is mentioned in Skanda Purana and that Skanda Purana is mentioned in [Bhagavata Purana](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/13/4-9), does this all of them are written around 12th century AD?

Comment: Most puranas have been proved to be interpolated

Comment: Describing future events doesn't mean they are written recently or they were interpolated. Puranas do mention events of next Manvantaras, does that mean they were written in next Manvanatara?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Okay I agree, but please see the footnotes under each pages.

Comment: @Ajay We cannot be sure of interpolations. Many things should be considered and this is most difficult task to do. What footnotes say is opinion of translator. You can take them for grain of salt. Also, there is no single opinion of interpolations. Different Schools have different opinions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer So, how can we explain that a Jain king and Vyasa came in the same chapter?

Comment: @TheDestroyer for example, Bhagavata 12.1 clearly explains all of the kings in future tense, but here there is no future tense.

Comment: @Ajay Sometimes the Puranas describe future events in the past tense, sometimes they describe them in the future tense.  As far as how a Jain king and Vyasa can be in the same chapter, Vyasa and the king aren't interacting, Vyasa is talking about future events involving that king.  In any case, even if that one chapter of the Skanda Purana is an interpolation, that does not imply that the Skanda Purana itself is a later text.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I totally agree with you. But the total number of verses in skanda Purana is given in bhagavata Purana

Comment: @Ajay Yes, so what?  I am sure that if you take any existing manuscript of the Skanda Purana, the number of verses will not be exactly 81,100.

Comment: @Ajay one should also note that many names are reused across Hinduism especially in rulers. There have been half a dozen Vikramadityas for example. It does not mean that the latest Vikramaditya is the one who helped Indra. Sometimes it's the intent of the ruler / courtiers to use the name to elevate oneself to the importance associated with the name, or the prophecies associated with that name.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I already know that

Comment: @user1952500 That's why I asked another question regarding his identity

Comment: @Ajay So even if one chapter of the Skanda Purana is a possible interpolation, that does not mean that either the Skanda Purana or the Srimad Bhagavatam are recent texts.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm curious to know your take on evolution.